# How to install bitnami stack(.run file) by using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, bitnami

I am trying to install .run files which I downloaded from https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/39461/bitnami-wordpress-3.9.2-0-linux-installer.run

But when I try to run it nothing happens (I have used text mode too)

How to install .run files in Linux by using SSH?

Comment: what command did you type to get text mode ? did'nt you get any error message ? In my environment, `./bitnami-wordpress-3.9.2-0-linux-installer.run --mode text` works fine.

Comment: I am running it using SSH when I type the command I dont get anything response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check you are using the correct binary (32bit or 64bit). You can use "uname -a" to see your current Linux architecture.
2. Change the file permissions:

   ```
   chmod 755 bitnami-*.run
   ```
3. Run the file:

   ```
   ./bitnami*.run --mode text
   ```

I hope it helps